# LAPACK function dgtsv giving unresolved external symbol with c++/Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2017, lapack

I am trying to compile a code under Windows10/Visual Studio 2017, for this code I have to use the `dgtsv` function of the LAPACK library.

I've linked Visual Studio with my *BLAS* and *LAPACK* libraries and copied the dll's to system32.

I've also installed *MinGW* with the g++ and fortran compiler.

```
extern "C" {
    void dgtsv(int*, int*, double*, double*, double*, double*, int*, int*);
}
```

But the compiler gives me the following error:

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol dgtsv referenced in function "private: void __cdecl"
```

Thank you for any advice you could give me.

Comment: How did you install the BLAS and LAPACK libraries? Are they compiled from MinGW? Because that might be an issue.

Comment: I used the prebuilt libraries found here: http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/index.html#libraries I then linked the folder where the .lib files were to Visual Studio following the instructions on the page.

Comment: Can you give us any more information? What's the msbuild command, or if you're using an IDE, what does your project file look like? How are you linking to them? 

Are you using the prebuild MinGW or Visual Studio libraries (they are not the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add an underscore after the function name, i.e. :

```
extern "C" {
    void dgtsv_(int*, int*, double*, double*, double*, double*, int*, int*);
}
```